# Integrating a php to html

Tags: php, javascript, html

Got two questions:
How can i intgrate a php script to a html document that:

1. should do his work at the documents startup and return a integer, which can be handled by javascript?
2. should do his work after a link is clicked and uses the links id?

lets create a example project:
1. php-name: start.php
2. php-name: click.php

html-code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

        });
</head>
<body>
        <p><a class="links" id="l1" href="http://www.google.com/">Boerse</a></p>
        <p><a class="links" id="l2" href="http://www.google.ch/">My Gully</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please explain your question better. I don't really understand what your issue is.

Comment: You can't write PHP code to do something after a link is clicked, without reloading a whole new page or sending an AJAX request. PHP code lives on your server, and it does all its work before a document is ever sent to the user. However, you can write an HTML page that uses some PHP to insert calculated values.

Comment: Please only ask one question at once (and it would sound complicated, too). Anyway, searching is a useful tool on this site, too. I can tell you you are not the first one here on this website who is dropping such a kind of question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** With javascript you could use jquery to perform a `POST HTTP Request` that simply posts  something like 'BeenSent' with data = 1. Then php checks to see if that isset. If it is then send back the variable to jquery as the function at the end of the ajax() method.

Here's an example

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "getInt.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {BeenSent: 1},
        cache: false,
        successCondition: function(result) {

        alert("getInt.php echo'd this out on it's file when I sent the request. The content it echo'd back was: " + result);

        }
});
```

---

**2.**
For the links you could simply perform a `GET` HTTP Request, or you could simply define the element's id within the link... like so...

```
<p><a class="links" id="l1" href="http://www.example.com/?elementid=l1">Hey! I'm a link!</a></p>
```

---

Hope this helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

For your first question: An ajax call is probably the nicest way to do it, but you could also do a kind of ugly solution. Have the php-function echo out the value to a hidden element, then fetch the value inside that element from your document.ready function in javascript.

```
 function GetInteger() {
     return 10;
}

echo '<span style="display:none" id="test">' . GetInteger() . '</span>';


$(document).ready(function(){
     var theValue = $("#test").html();
}
```

For the second question I would create onclick events that made ajax calls with the wanted value as a parameter, alternatively add the id as a get parameter to the querystring.